# Show warnings from the tidyverse all the time

Tags: tidyverse, deprecation-warning, verbosity

I am using a deprecated feature from the tidyverse. So a warning is produced that finishes like this:

This warning is displayed once every 8 hours.
Call `lifecycle::last_lifecycle_warnings()` to see where this
warning was generated.

My question is how to always show the warnings from the tidyverse, not just every 8 hours.

I have seen this solution in Posit Community:

`options(lifecycle_verbosity = "warning")`

but does not work for me.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. The warning message is "This warning is displayed once every 8 hours." The question is how to not wait 8 hours to verify a fix? The solution in Posit Community (formerly RStudio) seems to be more about setting your own deprecated warnings inside functions. Not a way to turn back on a snoozed warning produced inside someone else's function (in my case by rlang). And yes, restarting the r session (the nuclear option) does work, but that substantially slows down the debugging process. Perhaps there something that can manually be reset or a cookie-like-thing deleted?

Answer (score 1):

The correct spell is:

```
options("lifecycle_verbosity"="warning")
```

since `options()` expects a string type argument.

You can check current state with:

```
getOption("lifecycle_verbosity")
```

Reference: https://rdrr.io/r/base/options.html

Comment: Quoting the argument name will make no difference and isn't considered correct style. The example section of the reference you linked shows `options(name = "value")` as in OP, not `options("name" = "value")`.

Comment: Believe me I have tried it before posting and `options("lifecycle_verbosity"="warning")` works.